# Question about MySQL Stored Query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am querying a table that has classified ads in it. I need to have find all of the ads that are current (from between now and their expiration date), but all I want is the category that they are in and how many there are from each category. Here is what I have but can't get it to work.

```
SELECT AdType.AdTypeID,
       AdType.AdDescription,
       Class_Ads.AdTypeID,
       Class_Ads.DateSubmitted
FROM Class_Ads
INNER JOIN AdType ON Class_Ads.AdTypeID = AdType.AdTypeID
WHERE Class_Ads.DateSubmitted BETWEEN NOW() 
      AND (date_add(Class_Ads.DateSubmitted,INTERVAL 2 MONTH))
GROUP BY AdType.AdDescription
```

What I want the outcome to look like is:

category1 (5 ads)
category2 (2 ads)
etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(Class_Ads.Id),
       AdType.AdDescription
FROM Class_Ads
INNER JOIN AdType ON Class_Ads.AdTypeID = AdType.AdTypeID
WHERE Class_Ads.DateSubmitted BETWEEN NOW() 
      AND (date_add(Class_Ads.DateSubmitted,INTERVAL 2 MONTH))
GROUP BY AdType.AdDescription
```

Comment: Assuming there is an id column in the Class_Ads table.